# FIFOs: writting without reading. Where did the bytes go?

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I have the following two programs, a reader and a writer. The reader opens a named pipe (previously created with `mkfifo fifo.txt`) in read-only mode, sleeps for 15 seconds, and then closes the pipe (without reading anything).

The writer, opens the fifo in write-only mode, writes "hi" and then `close` the pipe.

```
// reader
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("fifo.txt", O_RDONLY);
    sleep(15);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

// writer
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("fifo.txt", O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "hi", 3);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I execute both programs in parallel in a terminal with `$ ./reader & ./writer &`, and then, once the `writer` has finished (and the reader is sleeping), I try to read `fifo.txt` with `cat fifo.txt` to see what happens. I tried to read from the fifo also after the reader has finished, and there's no way to read the 3 bytes written from the pipe. Only the `./reader` can read it before closing the pipe.

So if no one reads from the pipe, but the pipe still exists, what happened with those 3 bytes? How does the kernel, in general, manages who can read what (imagine a very general situation where several readers are opening the fifo, in non-blocking mode for instance, trying to read, and then leave)?

## Experiment

I modified the writer to write two different 3-byte long strings, and also modified the reader to read 3 bytes at most:

```
// reader
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[3] = {'\0'};

    int fd = open("fifo.txt", O_RDONLY);
    sleep(15);
    ssize_t bytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("[Reader] Read %s (%d chars)\n", buf, (int)bytes); fflush(stdout);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

// writer
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("fifo.txt", O_WRONLY);
    sleep(2);
    write(fd, "hi", 3);
    write(fd, "ha", 3);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I launch one writer and two readers at once and one reader is able to read "hi", and the other reader is able to read "ha". If I increase the buffer size to 10, then one reader reads "hi\0ha\0" and the other reader reads 0 bytes.

My guess is that the kernel manages some kind of "queue" of the processes that had the fifo opened at the time the write happened, and only those processes are the ones that can read from the pipe, but I would like to know the exact details of how the kernel manages who can read what and when.

Comment: The first read to execute gets the first data to be sent.

Comment: You can't ignore the context where the `open` happened, because reading a fifo through a fd that was opened after the write, blocks, which means that such "read" have no visibility of the write operation, while the data is still on the "buffer" of the queue. So things are a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html for an introduction

Comment: When all readers and writers close a pipe with unread data, the kernel frees the pipe's internal buffer and the unread data is discarded